# problem with object properties and kivy.properties

Tags: python, kivy

I have class Data with properties path. I have ScreenManager with 2 Screen. First screen edit path. Second screen show path. But when I change path, second screen don't show changes. How to fix it?

OS: linux
version python: 3.7.3
version Kivy: 1.10.1

main.py

```py
class Data(object):
    path = ""

main_data = Data()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    path = Property(main_data.path)

class FindFile(Screen):
    temp_path = ""

    def set_data(self):
        main_data.path = self.temp_path

    def update_path(self, give_path):
        if give_path != "":
            self.temp_path = give_path
            self.ids["print_path"].text = give_path
```

Main.kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    Label:
        id: label_path
        text: root.path

<FindFile>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: print_path
            size_hint: 1, .1
            text: root.temp_path
        FileChooserIconView:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            on_selection: root.update_path(self.selection and self.selection[0] or "")
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple problems here. First, your `Screen` instances should have `name` property set, to facilitate accessing and switching `Screens`. Second, you haven't established any connection between your `path` objects. If you assign the name `main` to your `MainScreen`, you can set the `path` value in the `MainScreen` by modifying the `update_path()` method of `FindFile` as:

```
def update_path(self, give_path):
    if give_path != "":
        self.temp_path = give_path
        self.ids["print_path"].text = give_path
        self.manager.get_screen('main').path = give_path
```